# Object: entity.ENTITY[ id=null ] is not a known entity type

Tags: jpa, persistence, eclipselink

this is a similar post to one I have seen before regarding this exception but I am utterly lost.  I have yet to persist an entity to a database using JPA, although I have read from tables using it no problem.  My setup is Netbeans 7.1 using Glassfish 3.1.1, EclipseLink is my persistence provider.  I have a very simple scenario where I just want to test writing a persons name and age into the database and having the id auto increment.  Its an MySql database with the fields: Id, FirstName and Age.  Heres my code:

Web servlet to take in name and age from html form:

```
    @Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {

    String userPath = request.getServletPath();

    if(userPath.equals("/addUser")){

        //get request parameters from form
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String age = request.getParameter("age");

        //set request attributes to be used by forwarded page
        request.setAttribute("name", name);
        request.setAttribute("age", age);

        //create manager class to add person to database
        Manager manager = new Manager();
        manager.addPerson(name, age);

        userPath = "/result";
    }

    // use RequestDispatcher to forward request internally
    String url = "/WEB-INF/view" + userPath + ".jsp";

    try {
        request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Manager class that takes in name and age, creates a person object and persists it.

```
public class Manager {

private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "FormPU";
private static EntityManagerFactory factory;

public Manager() {
}

public void addPerson(String name, String age) {

    factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
    EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();

    Persons persons = new Persons();
    persons.setName(name);
    persons.setAge(age);

    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(persons);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
}
}
```

Persons entity class:

```
    /**
    *
    * @author esmiala
    */
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "persons")
    @XmlRootElement
    @NamedQueries({
      @NamedQuery(name = "Persons.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Persons p"),
      @NamedQuery(name = "Persons.findById", query = "SELECT p FROM Persons p WHERE  
      p.id = :id"),
      @NamedQuery(name = "Persons.findByFirstName", query = "SELECT p FROM Persons p 
      WHERE p.firstName = :firstName"),
      @NamedQuery(name = "Persons.findByAge", query = "SELECT p FROM Persons p WHERE 
      p.age = :age")})
public class Persons implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "Id")
private Integer id;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 255)
@Column(name = "FirstName")
private String firstName;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 255)
@Column(name = "Age")
private String age;

public Persons() {
}

public Persons(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Persons(Integer id, String firstName, String age) {
    this.id = id;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.age = age;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(String age) {
    this.age = age;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Persons)) {
        return false;
    }
    Persons other = (Persons) object;
    if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "entity.Persons[ id=" + id + " ]";
}
```

}

Persistence.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com 
    /xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
     <persistence-unit name="FormPU" transaction-type="JTA">
     <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
     <jta-data-source>jdbc/form</jta-data-source>
     <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties/>
    </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

Note:  I have also tried setting exclude-unlisted-classes tag to true and list the class seperately but that didn't work either.

The exception:

```
    WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Controller]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet  
    Controller threw exception
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: entity.persons[ id=null ] is not a   
    known entity type.
atorg.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObject
    ForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4141)
atorg.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.   
    persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:368)
at manager.Manager.addPerson(Manager.java:36)
at controller.Controller.doPost(Controller.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
```

...and so on.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

`<exclude-unlisted-classes>` doesn't work as you would expect - the very presence of this element in `persistence.xml` disables automatic discovery of `@Entity` classes, no matter what's inside it.

Also, `@Entity(name="persons")` is probably not what you want, use `@Entity @Table (name="persons")` instead.

Comment: I deleted the entity class and the persistence xml file and generated new ones using Netbeans Entity Classes from Database wizard.  It produces the following but still doesn't work.  Ill edit in the new entity class...

Answer (score 1):

So you say you can read the class fine, but get an error persisting a new instance?

Can you update an object that you read?

It seems you are having some kind of class loader issue.  Somehow you have the class on your classpath twice, or have two different class loaders.  The object you are passing to persist is from a different class loader than the one JPA is using.  You can check the class loader of what was read, and of the object being persisted to see how they differ.

Have you redeployed you app, or hotdeployed?  Does it work if you shut down/restart the server properly.  Ensure you are closing your old EntityManagerFactory before redeploying.

Comment: Hi, yes I have redeployed, restarted the server, etc but nothing works.  "It seems you are having some kind of class loader issue. Somehow you have the class on your classpath twice, or have two different class loaders. The object you are passing to persist is from a different class loader than the one JPA is using. You can check the class loader of what was read, and of the object being persisted to see how they differ."  Can you go into that a bit more, im not sure what that means.  It isn't picking up the entity at all.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning youe concrete problem, try to see if this [link](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Development/JPA_2.0/metamodel_api#DI_101%3a_20100218%3a_Descriptor.javaClass_is_null_on_a_container_EM_for_a_specific_case) helps.

Anyway, the way you are instantiating the EntityManager is not thread safe.

You can see [here](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/ejb_3_persistence_jpa_for) why. Or, better, you can use NetBeans' wizard for creating JPA controller classes from entity classes, and see how it injects the EntityManager:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
```

See also that the controller classes (the equivalent of your Manager POJO) have the `Stateless` annotation. This is because you can safely inject an EJB (in this case the EntityManager) only in an object whose lifecycle is managed by the web container (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipjf.html) for further reference about Accessing Enterprise Beans).

Comment: Thanks for the info, ill have a look.